# What is the equivalent of nslookup in vb.net?

Tags: .net, vb.net, cmd, dsn, nslookup

I use nslookup on my cmd line and I am then returned my standard server ip address but I can't seem to get this address using vb.net. I did manage to read up on DSN and vb.net but it still made little sense to me could somebody help me get this ip address?

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Your question is not very clear.

Comment: well I need to get the standard server adress, I get this by typing nslookup into my command prompt, but I want vb.net to get this automatically however I dont know how

Answer (score 0):

Sample code from [MSDN website](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ipinterfaceproperties.dnsaddresses.aspx):

> The following code example displays the DNS addresses for the network
>   interfaces on the local computer.

```
Public Shared Sub DisplayDnsAddresses() 
    Dim adapters As NetworkInterface() = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()
    Dim adapter As NetworkInterface
    For Each adapter In  adapters

        Dim adapterProperties As IPInterfaceProperties = adapter.GetIPProperties()
        Dim dnsServers As IPAddressCollection = adapterProperties.DnsAddresses
        If dnsServers.Count > 0 Then
            Console.WriteLine(adapter.Description)
            Dim dns As IPAddress
            For Each dns In  dnsServers
                Console.WriteLine("  DNS Servers ............................. : {0}",dns.ToString() )
            Next dns
        End If
    Next adapter

End Sub 'DisplayDnsAddresses
```